# ordering by rows

Tags: select, count, sql-order-by

OK so I have a query I am trying to build.. I have 2 tables, table1 has a bunch of regular records as normal with a unique ID (auto increment) and table2 has records that include some of those ids from table1. I am trying to order by the highest records with that same ID in table1.. Heres what I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE table1.status = 1 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.tbl1_id = table1.id) 
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.id 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.tbl1_id = table1.id
WHERE table1.status = 1 
GROUP BY table1.id
ORDER BY COUNT(table2.tbl1_id) DESC
```

Comment: Should do... Have you changed it? (i.e. added additional columnns) If you add columns to the `SELECT` you need to add them to the `GROUP BY` or use the approach in Cybernate's answer.

Comment: theres thousands of records on both tables lol, and I've tried both yours and Cybermates, its not returning the correct records..

Comment: Perhaps you haven't explained your requirements clearly enough then. The queries in both mine and Cybernate's answers will get the count of the number of matching records in `table2` for each `table1.id` (**including where the count is zero**) and order by that `count`. is that not what you meant? If you wanted to exclude ones with a count of zero you would use an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: OK, got it :) yours worked :) Thanks both Martin and Cybermate!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.cnt
  FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT tbl1_id, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM table2
        GROUP BY tbl1_id
    ) b
 ON a.id = b.tbl1_id  
WHERE table1.status = 1 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: If there are no corresponding records in table2 for an id do you still want to show the record from table1 in your result and if yes should they be displayed with a count of 0?